# Passing an array to a function declared in two different ways

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++14, declaration

So, I have declared an array using the <array> header in C++, and now I want to pass this array to a function that doesn't return any value but displays each element in a new line on the terminal. Following is the code for that.

```
// to pass an array to a function
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void myFunction(int arr[5]); // function prototype

int main () {
    array <int, 5> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    myFunction(arr);
}

// function definition
void myFunction(int arr[5]) {
    for (size_t counter{0}; counter < 5; ++counter) {
        cout << arr[counter] << endl;
    }
}
```

The above code isn't working.

```
arr no suitable conversion function from "std::array<int, 5ULL>" to "int *" existsC/C++(413)
```

...

```
demo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
demo.cpp:11:16: error: cannot convert 'std::array<int, 5>' to 'int*'
   11 |     myFunction(arr);
      |                ^~~
      |                |
      |                std::array<int, 5>
demo.cpp:6:21: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void myFunction(int*)'
    6 | void myFunction(int arr[5]); // function prototype
      |
```

These two are the error messages getting shown to me.
Now on the other hand, if I declare the array differently, without using the standard library header, it works fine.

```
arr[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // instead of 
                        // array <int, 5> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

It produces the following result

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I just want to know what the array declarations have to do with any of this? If there is a way of doing this using the declaration with <array> header, what is it?

Comment: `void myFunction(int arr[5]);` should be `void myFunction(const array<int,5>& arr);`

Comment: `std::array<int, 5>` is not implicitly convertible to `int*`, so the function appropriate signature would be `void myFunction(std::array<int, 5> const& arr);` Alternatively you can call the function in your code as `myFunction(arr.data());`

Comment: Thanks, didn't expected it to be that quick though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that your function expects an `int*` but you're passing a `array <int, 5>` but since there is no implicit conversion from `array <int, 5>` to `int*`, we get the mentioned error.

You can also use `std::array::data` as `myFunction(arr.data());` to make this [work](https://onlinegdb.com/brU6U7bcw).

---

The reason your second case works when you create array like `int arr[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` and then pass it like `myFunction(arr)` is because a built in array **decays** to a pointer to its first element(`int*` in your example) due to **type decay**. So in this modified case, the type of the argument and the parameter matches and this works.

Comment: Won't `std::array<int,5>::data()` be a viable alternative?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, it will be viable here i've added it in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you can compile with C++20, I would strongly suggest you change your function to:

```
void myFunction(std::span<const int> arr) {
    for (const int elm : arr) {
        std::cout << elm << std::endl;
    }
}
```

By using span as the parameter, your function can be called with any type of continous int of any size, eg.

```
std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
std::array arr{1,2,3,4,5};
int oldArray[] = {1,2,3,4};

myFunction(vec);
myFunction(arr);
myFunction(oldArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your formal argument must have the same type as your factual.

If you try to call with `std::array<int, 5>` then declare your function like `void myFunction(std::array<int, 5> arr)`.

Need to know that such declaration means copy your array. It may have no need. Then you may use a reference.
If need just to read without change and move then `const lvalue` reference is enough. Ready prototype:

`void myFunction (std::array<int,5> const &arr);`